# Styling <hr> tag and text in mailer css

Tags: html, css

I want to setup a mailer styling like below (this is a mobile view which is most important).

[image: mail view]

I don't know how to achieve such a view. I was trying something below:

```
<h1>Hi there,</h1>
<p>Thank you for signing up!</p>
<hr>
<p>You're almost there. Before starting with your journey, we want to make sure that your email address is correct. Please click here to complete your subscription.</p>
<hr>
<h2>Your account</h2>
...
```

with CSS:

```
  h1 {
    color: #0C0C0D;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    line-height: 33px;
    margin-bottom: 33px;
  }
  hr {
    width: 50%;
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background: #333;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ccc, #333, #ccc);
  }
  p {
    color: #0C0C0D;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    line-height: 20px;
  }
```

With the above css it looks terrible (iPhone view):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with **vh** unit instead of the percentage.

```
<h1>Hi there,</h1>
<p>Thank you for signing up!</p>
<hr class="hr1">
<p>You're almost there. Before starting with your journey, we want to make sure that your email address is correct. Please click here to complete your subscription.</p>
<hr class="hr2">
<h2>Your account</h2>

  h1 {
    color: #0C0C0D;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    line-height: 33px;
    margin-bottom: 33px;
  }
  hr {
    width: 50vh;
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background: #333;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ccc, #333, #ccc);

  }
 .hr1{
      margin: 30px 0;
  }

 .hr2{
      margin: 20px  0 0 0;
  }

  p {
    color: #0C0C0D;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    line-height: 20px;
  }
```

Comment: Ok but how to take a space between `Thank you for signing up!` and the line like in the first screen?